# zxing libraries recognition issues

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

With the zxing developing a barcode reader app .
The type of bar code recognition EAN13.
There currently are well aware of the specific bar code recognition is devised .

Would you ever zxing library or something compelling alternative to earn recognition ?
Or ask if you know the alternative introduced remarkable library.

The test phone Galaxy Note 2 (android 4.4.2).

Comment: Play Services now supports that format. Read more at http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html

Comment: @KaneO'Riley Thank You, Good Info :)

Comment: @YoungkiKim, Google play services is not open source. If you want to find an alternative open source Barcode library instead of ZXing, you can try [ZBar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar).

Answer (score 0):

My app scanning was not sensitive and very slow with Zxing. I've just replaced it with Google Machine Learning kit. Very happy with the result. There is also a bonus, multiple barcodes can be scanned at a time.